# Can I get thumbnail of taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, post-thumbnails

```
<?php
            $args = array(
                'type'                     => 'itineraries',
                'child_of'                 => 0,
                'parent'                   => '',
                'orderby'                  => 'name',
                'order'                    => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'               => 1,
                'hierarchical'             => 1,
                'exclude'                  => '',
                'include'                  => '',
                'number'                   => '',
                'taxonomy'                 => 'travel_locations',
                'pad_counts'               => false );
            $categories = get_categories($args);
            $attachments = get_children( $args );   

                    foreach ($categories as $category):
// set up a new query for each category, pulling in related posts.
$services = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'itineraries',
        'showposts' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'travel_locations',
                'terms'     => array( $category->slug ),
                'field'     => 'slug'
            )
        )
    )
);
?> 
<h3><?php echo $category->name; ?></h3>
<ul>
<?php while ($services->have_posts()) : $services->the_post(); ?>
<li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php
// Reset things, for good measure
$services = null;
wp_reset_postdata();
// end the loop
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Taxonomy terms don't have thumbnails. If you've used a plugin to add that feature, then it would have documentation telling you how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use advanced custom field plugin for better use

```
 // get the current taxonomy term
$term = get_queried_object();

// here is the taxonomy image
$image = get_field('image', $term);
```

Or

```
You can use free plugin in your template

 URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-image/
 if (function_exists('get_wp_term_image'))

{
$meta_image = get_wp_term_image($term_id); 
//It will give category/term image url 
}

echo $meta_image; // category/term image url
```